# Find function for given values

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

I have some trouble solving the following (scalar valued) problem. What I know: Scalar values of $f(a,b)$, $a$ and $b$ are given. Now I am searching for a scalar function $g()$, so that it holds

$f(a,b) = a \cdot g(a) + b \cdot g(b)$.

How should I approach this?

**EDIT:**

After thinking a while, here is a simpler version of my problem. Suppose I know every discrete value $f_i$ of function $f()$ for the parameter $a_i$ and $b_i$. How should I find a solution for $G()$ (or every $G_i$), if it should hold

$f_i = G_i(a_i) + G_i(b_i)$.

Also, there exists a formula for $a_i$ and $b_i$. So they are dependend,

$a_i = x_i - b_i$ with $x_i$ is also known.

I am writing this in "discrete" form since the values for $f()$ and $a$ and $b$ are also caluculated numerically.

Comment: This is not clear.  Of course, such a function $g$ doesn't exist in general, though of course it might for some particular $f$.  Did you have a function in mind?

Comment: $g()$ should probably be some polynom. But this is not important.

Comment: The form of $f$ will dictate the form of $g$, if $g$ exists.  Note that, if your expression is to hold, we must have $f(a,a)=2ag(a)$ which implies $g(a)=\frac {f(a,a)}{2a}$.  But again, that assumes that $g$ exists, which it usually doesn't.

Comment: $f()$ is a polynom like curve. In my case, it do not need a matematical expression for $g()$. It would be sufficient, if there would be the option to somehow numerically compute the values for $g()$ and then store them in a table. But I just do not know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Should say:  I am not sure what you mean by "scalar" here.  I am assuming that $a,b\in \mathbb R$ and $f$ is a function from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, or something like that (maybe you want a different field than $\mathbb R$, who knows?).  If you meant something else you should edit to clarify.

Comment: I gave you a closed formula (well, "closed" assuming $f$ is known).  It either works or it doesn't.  If it doesn't, that means that no function $g$ exists which, as I say, is the expected outcome.

Comment: You can consider interpolating $f$, for example using cubic splines?

Comment: Yes, interpolating is possible.